# Ответ на сообщения пользователя в группе через copy_message в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Ситуация такая: пользователь пишет боту. Бот перенаправляет сообщение в группу. Там один из участников отвечает. Бот копирует сообщение и отвечает пользователю.

Все реализовано. Но если пользователь защитил профиль от пересылки, то ответить не получается. Так как нельзя вытащить ID пользователя из пересылаемого сообщения.

> NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Помогите реализовать метод сохранения ID пользователя, либо как его можно вытащить в данном случае

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
group_id = GROUP_ID
    
@bot.message_handler()
def reply_mess(message):
    if message.reply_to_message:
        bot.copy_message(message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    else:
        bot.forward_message(group_id, message.chat.id, message.message_id)        

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Если пользователь пишет напрямую боту то можно попробовать message.chat.id

Comment: Отвечая на пересылаемое сообщение пользователя в группе message.chat.id выдаст же ID текущей группы

Comment: Да, я уточник в первом сообщение, что это будет работать только когда пользователь напишет лично боту.